# pass multiple search terms to text browser via bash_aliases in prompt

Tags: bash, shell-script, alias

I want to achieve a bash alias so that I can type just:

```
$> lynxsearch most popular unix text browsers
$> w3msearch most popular unix text browsers
```

(or the search terms within quotes or brackets)

To have initial loading on a search result page already.

I have the followings in my .bash_aliases, but it works only if I have a single search term. And it does not work with multiple search terms.

```
alias w3g='f(){ w3m https://www.duckduckgo.com/?q=$@;  unset -f f; }; 
f'
alias lyg='f(){ lynx https://www.duckduckgo.com/?q=$@;  unset -f f;
}; f'
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

In your example the URL would become:

```
https://www.duckduckgo.com/?q=most popular unix text browsers
```

Which is not a valid URL since it has spaces.  You could replace the spaces with either `%20` or even simpler `+`.

Lets get rid of your aliases because they are sort of just weaker functions anyway, and make a proper function:

```
lynxsearch () {
    local search=$@
    search="${search// /%20}"
    lynx "https://www.duckduckgo.com/?q=$search"
}
```

Put this in your `.bashrc` instead of `.bash_aliases`.

Comment: +1 Just out of curiosity, why recommend to put the function in `~/.bashrc` instead of `~/.bash_aliases` ?  Arguably a function is not an alias is not a function, etc... But in this case their objectives are pretty much  aligned.

Comment: @Cbhihe: Since the `.bash_aliases` file is sourced you could put functions, environmental variables, etc it in but since it's called `.bash_aliases` I figured it would be better not to put a function in it.  Honestly I have never seen a need for the file though I just put all my functions/aliases in `.bashrc`

Comment: Well, this is a topic for another venue perhaps, but when you have enough material (as I do) - i.e. more than 400 lines in `~/.bash_aliases` for different Lx platforms I use - you tend to want to segregate things. So I don't mean to preach or teach without an invitation, but it's actually good practice to separate stuff in that case. I keep all things Python, shell history, key bindings, color and prompt definitions, communication from the shell and mail service related in `~/.bashrc`, all my aliases and alias like functions  in `~/.bash_aliases` and env-var related in `/.profile`.

Comment: (continued)    It is much easier to read, maintain and debug that way. A non-negligible advantage also is to keep your `~/.bashrc` small , the which induces a response time when spawning a new `bash` shell, much reduced compared to what it would be if it contained the 400 additional lines I have in  `~/.bash_aliases`.

Comment: What is an "Alias like function"?  Technically all functions are alias-like but no function **is** an alias.  Also I don't think `bash_aliases` is actually a defined thing but more of a user hack.  Regardless it literally says **aliases** and not **functions**

Comment: Yeah `.bash_aliases` isn't a bash thing, it's a file that some distributions include to help segregate things.  Bash itself has no idea whether it exists or not unless it's explicitly sourced by another standard file.  However if it's being sourced by your .bashrc anyway it will not increase performance in any way.  You could also make a `.cbhihe_stuff` file and it would be no more official.

Comment: Also my `.bashrc` is 357 lines and it only takes .7 seconds to source it